# Computing: $\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{x\log{\frac{1}x}} \, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can i integrate following definite integral?

I tried integrating by parts which obviously did not work.

$$I=\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{x\log{\frac{1}x}} \, \mathrm dx$$

Comment: Have you tried with $x=e^u$.?

Comment: yeah, it was a stupid question.don't bother.

Comment: @AkashRana Mathematica says that the answer is about $0.608494$.

Comment: @MyGlasses. I think that you forgot some powers. The result comes from the gamma function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Indeed. After doing $x=e^u$, one gets $-\int_{-\infty}^0e^{\frac43u}\sqrt[3]u\,\mathrm du$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos. Exactly ! Then the value in terms of the gamma function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{x\log{\frac{1}x}} \, \mathrm dx$$

set $ u =-\ln x =\ln\frac{1}{x}$ then $dx = -e^{-u} du$ and 
$$I=\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{x\log{\frac{1}x}} \, \mathrm dx =\int_0^\infty e^{-u/3}e^{-u} u^{1/3}  du = \int_0^\infty e^{-4/3u} u^{1/3}du.$$ then set $v= 4/3u $
 so that 
$$I=3/4\int_0^\infty e^{-v} (3/4v)^{1/3}dv  = {\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{4/3}\int_0^\infty e^{-v} v^{1/3}dv ={\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{4/3}\Gamma(\frac{4}{3}) = {\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{4/3}\frac{1}{3}\Gamma(\frac{1}{3}).$$

Comment: (+1) I was just about to post an answer by using the substitution $x=e^{-3u/4}$, which is essentially the same as yours.

Answer (score 3):

It's nesseccery to write the solution regarding to my incorrect comment. With $x=e^u$ we have
$$I=\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{x\log{\frac{1}x}} \, \mathrm dx=-\int_{-\infty}^0 \sqrt[3]{e^u}u^\frac13 e^u \, \mathrm du=-\int_{-\infty}^0 \sqrt[3]{e^u}u^\frac13 e^u \, \mathrm du=\left(\dfrac34\right)^\frac43\int_0^{\infty} t^\frac13 e^{-t}\, \mathrm dt=\left(\dfrac34\right)^\frac43\Gamma(\dfrac43)$$
where $\dfrac43u=-t$.