# definite integral $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{x\log\frac 1x} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Please solve:

$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt[3]{x\log\frac 1x} $

I have tried substituting but every time it is getting more complicated. Please help.

Comment: $\log$ is $\ln$ or $\log_{10}$?

Comment: seen here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396605/int-01-sqrt3x-log-frac1x-mathrm-dx/2396634#2396634

Comment: It must be a coincidence: same two users answer the same question [twice](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2396605/9464).

Comment: It is while answering that I remember that I have answered typical question in the pass then I went through my answers list . See that I am the first to flag this post as duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With substitutions $\ln\dfrac1x=u$ and then $\dfrac43u=v$ we have
$$I=\int_0^\infty u^\frac13e^{-\frac43u}du=\left(\dfrac34\right)^\frac43\int_0^\infty v^\frac13e^{-v}dv=\left(\dfrac34\right)^\frac43\Gamma\left(\dfrac43\right)$$

Comment: $\Gamma$ is the upper gamma function yes?

Answer (score 2):

set $u = -\ln x$ then $dx -e^{-u} du$

$$I=\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{x\log{\frac{1}x}} \, \mathrm dx$$

then set $v= 4/3u $
 so that 
$$I=3/4\int_0^\infty e^{-v} (3/4v)^{1/3}dv  = {\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{4/3}\int_0^\infty e^{-v} v^{1/3}dv ={\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{4/3}\Gamma(\frac{4}{3}) = {\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{4/3}\frac{1}{3}\Gamma(\frac{1}{3}).$$