# Evaluation of the definite Integral $\int_0^1 \sqrt [3] {x \log\left(\frac{1}{x} \right)}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

What kind of substitution should i use and how can I get rid of $\log{\frac{1}{x}}$from the square root
Note cube root is over both x and $\log{\frac{1}{x}}$.

Comment: I see , Thanks Boss

Comment: This was asked before at [Computing: $\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{x\log{\frac{1}x}} \, \mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396605/computing-int-01-sqrt3x-log-frac1x-mathrm-dx)

Answer (score 3):

Write the original problem as:
$$I=\int_0^1 -x^{\frac{1}{3}}\ln^{\frac{1}{3}}(x)dx$$

Let: $~~\ln(x)=-u^3, ~~~x=e^{-u^3},~~~dx=-3u^2e^{-u^3} du$,

and plug in the substitution:

$$\begin{align}
I=\int^\infty_0 3u^3\cdot e^{-\frac{4}{3}u^3}du
\end{align}$$

Let: $~~t=\frac{4}{3}u^3$

$$\begin{align}
I=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\int_0^\infty t^{\frac{1}{3}} e^{-t} dt=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)
\end{align}$$